# How can I create fillable forms for my website that gives the user the ability ti submit online?

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, pdf

I am trying to create a website that will give the ability to the users to register online. I wanted to do the registration as an online form (or fillable pdf) that the users can submit, and I can catch the form on the back end and save it into a storage. What are some possible ways of doing this? I am building my website using Java, Spring Framework. 
Thank you

Comment: There are many good Spring MVC tutorials you can get help from. At the back end you can use jdbc or ORM like Hibernate.

Comment: I will look into it, thank you. I think the best way of getting information would be by creating a form using text boxes and labels, instead of a pdf file, and saving the data into a database.